# How to use Boost::bind with variable-length template parameters?

Tags: c++, boost

`boost::asio::thread_pool` is a very useful thread pool instance, but it doesn't limit the number of tasks. You can post as many tasks as you like into it. Sometimes it take lots of memory. And I want to implement a thread pool with limit to the number of tasks, using `boost::asio::thread_pool`.

Here is my code:

```cpp
class threadpool{
public:
    threadpool(int n):threads(n),thnum(n),count(0),stopflag(false){}
    ~threadpool(){
        stop();
    }
    void stop(){
        stopflag=true;
        cond.notify_all();
        threads.stop();
    }
    template<typename F, typename...Args>
    void post(F &&f, Args&&...args) {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mute);
        cond.wait(lock,[this]{
            return stopflag || count < 2*thnum;// task number less than 2x thread number
        });
        ++count;
        // The next line doesn't compile
        boost::asio::post(threads,boost::bind(&threadpool::post_func,this,std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }
private:
    boost::asio::thread_pool threads;
    int count;// task number
    int thnum;// thread number
    bool stopflag;
    boost::mutex mute;
    boost::condition_variable_any cond;

    template<typename F, typename...Args>
    void post_func(F &&f, Args&&...args){
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mute);
        --count;
        cond.notify_one();
        lock.unlock();
        auto func=boost::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        func();
    }
};
```

and I got:

```
../thpl.cpp: In instantiation of 'void threadpool::post(F&&, Args&& ...) [with F = void (print_task::*)(); Args = {print_task*}]':
../thpl.cpp:61:34:   required from here
../thpl.cpp:25:46: error: no matching function for call to 'bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, threadpool*, void (print_task::*)(), print_task*)'
         boost::asio::post(threads,boost::bind(&threadpool::post_func,this,std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

with lots of `note:` following.

So how to use Boost::bind with variable-length template parameters? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Why boost::bind? If you have variadic tempolates, you should use lambdas instead.

Comment: Lambda works! Thanks! But is lambda the only solution? I prefer using member functions.

Comment: You are using member fucntions with lambdas as well, I don't understand the question.

Comment: The lambda in `cond.wait` is a simple one. But I'm afraid the `post_func` will become more complicated, such as dealing with exceptions.

Comment: You can do far more in a lambda than with boost::bind. I don't even understand why you are using boost::bind instead of std::bind in this case.